# Online 3D modelling tool (similar to SketchUp)

Tags: webapp-rec, 3d

I'm looking for a web app which will allow me to create a 3D model of a cupboard I need to design for coursework. So that rules out Floorplanner.
I can't install or execute an .exe file on the school computers, so no SketchUp and the alternative is a web app.

Are there any around?

Answer (score 2):

You could try Autodesk's [Project Butterfly](https://butterfly.autodesk.com/). That looks to be webapp based CAD tool. I'm not sure what kind of export options it will provide though. But, it's free.

Taken from: http://butterfly.autodesk.com/blog/what-is-butterfly/

> Butterfly is a new and innovative
>   technology developed by the Autodesk
>   Israel team to bring the power of
>   AutoCAD, the world’s leading design
>   solution, to the Web for the first
>   time. Project Butterfly enables users
>   to view, edit, and share complex
>   designs and drawings using just a Web
>   browser.
>
> Dubbed as ”Google Docs for AutoCAD.”
>   Project Butterfly is considered by
>   industry experts to be one the most
>   complex and technically advanced web
>   applications today.

Comment: I took a look but it seems to be 2D only, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one tool [3Dvia](http://www.3dvia.com), it is mostly like sketchup and has a huge gallery
plus you can pull and make curves with it, this is the only feature that is not found in sketchup